# Hide/show specific rows on checkbox in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatables table, some of the rows in my table have the class `banned`. I want to exclude these rows on page load, show them when a checkbox is checked, and exclude them again if the checkbox is unchecked.

Here is my code so far

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="display_banned_songs" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
        <label>Display Banned Songs?</label>
    </div>
</div>

$('.ui.toggle.checkbox').checkbox({
    onChecked: function() {
        console.log('onChecked called');
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
           function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
              return true;
           }
        );
    },
    onUnchecked: function() {
        console.log('onUnchecked called');
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
           function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
              return !$(table.row(dataIndex).node()).hasClass('banned');
           }
        );
    },
    onChange: function() { table.draw() }
});
```

Currently, the rows are *not* excluded on page load, so I know that my `onUnchecked` method works, because I can see the rows on page load but when I check and then uncheck my checkbox, the specified rows are hidden and everything else shows.

I can't figure out why my `onChecked` function doesn't work, I basically need it to display *all* the rows (unless filtered by the search bar).

I'm also not sure how to hide the specified rows on page load.

How can I get my `onChecked` method working, and how can I hide the rows on page load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, you have some property-marker within your source data (like, property `banned: true`) for banned items and you applied that marker as a class to target table rows `<tr>` with something, like:

```
$('table').DataTable({
    ...
    createdRow: (tr, data) => data.banned ? $(tr).addClass('banned') : true
})
```

You may use DataTables [custom filtering feature](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search#Example) to filter out the rows, having class 'banned' when filtering checkbox is unchecked:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((_, __, idx) => !$(dataTable.row(idx).node()).hasClass('banned') || $('#display_banned_songs').prop('checked'))
```

Then you may simply redraw your table upon clicking filter checkbox:

```
$('#display_banned_songs').on('click', () => dataTable.draw());
```

Complete **demo** of that concept you might find below:

```js
//sample source data
const srcData = [{title:'Fixxxer',artist:'Metallica',banned:false},{title:'Humanity',artist:'Scorpions',banned:false},{title:'Turn the page',artist:'Metallica',banned:false},{title:'Baby one more time',artist:'Britney Spears',banned:true},{title:'Wrecking ball',artist:'Miley Cyrus',banned:true}];

//datatables initialization
const dataTable = $('table').DataTable({
  dom: 't',
  data: srcData,
  columns: [
    {data: 'title', title: 'Song Title'},
    {data: 'artist', title: 'Band/Artist'}
  ],
  createdRow: (tr, data) => data.banned ? $(tr).addClass('banned') : true
});

//custom filter based on 'banned' class of the row
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push((_, __, idx) => !$(dataTable.row(idx).node()).hasClass('banned') || $('#display_banned_songs').prop('checked'));

//show/hide banned
$('#display_banned_songs').on('click', () => dataTable.draw());
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script></head><body><div class="field"><div class="ui toggle checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="display_banned_songs" tabindex="0" class="hidden" checked><label>Display Banned Songs?</label></div></div><table></table></body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe on your page load you need to trigger checkbox to be ticked.

```
$('#display_banned_songs').trigger('change');
```

This way it will tick the checkbox on page load and show all the rows.

In regards to hiding the rows with banned class on the page load you could put the following code on your page load possibly and see if that does the trick:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).hasClass('banned');
   }
);

table.draw();
```

I hope this helps.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Could you please let me know what the other half is please?

Comment: I just edited the answer. See if that's what you need please.

Comment: No, my issue is that the method I use in `onChecked` does not work, there is no way to _un_hide the columns currently.